# Laravel - Cast de un boolean

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

intento hacer en un controlador de laravel una Collection dinámicamente, en función de los parámetros recibidos construir la query.

Recibo una url tipo esta
http://ejemplo.local/api/aliments/search/foodType?type=fish,egg

Recibo en types un array donde hago un explode y los pongo en otro array.
Este nuevo array es el que intento construir la colección.

```
        $types = explode(",", $typeRequest);

        foreach ($types as $type) {
        if ($type === 'fish') {
            array_push($typeFind,'is_fish');
        }
        if ($type === 'meat') {
            array_push($typeFind,'is_meat');
        }
        if ($type === 'egg') {
            array_push($typeFind,'has_egg');
        }
    }


    $aliments = Aliment::where('enabled',1);

    foreach ($typeFind as $type) {
        $aliments->where($type,1);
    }

    $aliments = $aliments->get();
```

Lo que intento construir es algo similar a esto

```
        $aliments = Aliment::where('enabled',1)
                ->where('is_meat',1)
                ->where('is_fish',1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Es mala práctica mandar arreglos por URL, en este caso lo más conveniente sería mandarlo directamente por post o por Ajax.
La mejor manera sería poniendo un form de la siguiente manera

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('tuRuta')}}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Y en el back
`$types=$request->input("type[]")`
De ahí ya sigues con tus validaciones